# Freeze/pause a web page activity to retrieve elements properties

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to parse data from a page which is constantly updated by JavaScript and Web Workers. I need to get all elements in a list but often when I try to retrieve element properties I receive `StaleElementReferenceException` because such element was already removed from DOM. Is there a way to temporarily freeze DOM or suspend Web Workers network activity so that I can parse everything without errors?

Comment: The only way to freeze DOM is "debugger" but it might cause issues with selenium and I don't think there's a way to turn it off outside of dev tools

Answer (score 0):

The [Window `stop()` Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_stop.asp) stops window loading and can be used as follows:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.stop();");
```

Comment: The page is already loaded at the time I'm parsing it. I need to stop JavaScript from updating the page content.